# Is it possible to link to the same page from wordpress page menu?

Tags: wordpress

I have a big one page wordpress site and a menu created from wordpress admin pages panel. I added everywhere in my main page such links like `<A NAME="gohere">` and similar. Now I need to add href's to the page menu name's like `<a href="#gohere">` Actually I do not know is it possible to do this from the wordpress admin page's menu or maybe anybody know where these pages are stored so that I could add the links manually in the file's. Thanks!

Tried plugin "Page Links to" and added something like `<A NAME="gohere">` as a link in where, but unfortunately plugin do not understand this,

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the `name` attribute of the a element. Instead, assign `ID` values to the elements of your page, for instance:

```
<a href="#foo">Link to foo</a>

<div id="foo">
<!-- Your foo content goes here -->
</div>
```

For your question: You can manually add links to your WordPress menu, entering custom values as the `href` attribute. To add a link, enter `#foo` in the URL field of the custom link in the menu admin section.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the WordPress's built in menu manager?  (Appearance -> Menus)

If so, then yes it should be fairly simple.

First you need to mark the areas within the page you want to link to - setting an ID to the element is enough.  So if you want the browser to scroll to the top of the latest posts when a link is clicked, for example, you need to add an ID to the tag that contains the latest posts.  Then give it a *unique* name (this is important).  So something like id="latest_posts_area" should do it.  Be warned though, you may need to edit the template files to do this, **so ensure you have taken a backup of your theme just in case you make any mistakes**.

So, if you have:

```
<div class="latest_posts">
```

You would edit it to be:

```
<div class="latest_posts" id="latest_posts_area">
```

Then, in the admin menu, when adding/editing a link, you simply set the URl as #latest_posts_area - then on every page that link is visible, clicking it will scroll the users browser to the to the top of the tag you added the ID to.